# Why does $j=f$ cause error in forest?

Tags: math-mode, forest

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [$j=f$]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

causes the following error.

```
ERROR: Extra }, or forgotten $.

--- TeX said ---
\forest@temp@nodeformat ...nchor=base](node@2){$j}
                                              ;
l.15 \end{forest}

--- HELP ---
The braces or math mode delimiters don't match properly. You probably
forgot a {, \[, \(, or $.
```

Comment: Why does it need protection?

Comment: Off-topic: http://ctan.org/pkg/prooftrees.

Comment: Ok, I'll choose an answer if you post it. Does prooftrees have the same problem?

Comment: I was thinking of a different syntax similar to that of a programming language in which syntax doesn't confuse humans.

Comment: Shell script is a bad example. Lisp languages(clojure, etc...) have little or no ambiguity in syntax. I'm learning haskell, so I can't say much about haskell.

Comment: Sašo asked me to answer this so I've converted the bulk of my comments to an answer and tidied up a bit here. I'd suggest you might like to do the same with your comments (although the bulk of the mess was mine, for sure).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*[Sašo asked me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28385887#28385887) if I would answer this and has assured me that the answer I gave in comments is the one he would give.*

`=` in the content of nodes and values, like `,`, requires protection with curly brackets because the way Forest stores the content is to add `content'=<content>` to the list of options for the node. This is a key-value list, so `=` and `,` both have the meanings they have in such lists and need protection. Hence, we need

```
[{$j=f$} ...
```

to avoid an attempt to read this as an attempt to assign the value `f$` to the key `$j$.

See page 22 of the manual on 'the bracket representation' for details.

I don't think this can rightly be called a 'problem' though. Any syntax has to use something. It is like asking whether something has the same 'problem' as TeX where the problem is that we have to write `\{` or something rather than `{`. Only in a word processor or similar where there is no markup can this be avoided. I don't see what alternative you envisage.

Of course, you might mean: why did they have to choose `=` when `=` is so useful in the content of nodes in proofs? Well, yes, but it is also intuitive for people to write things like `color=red` rather than, say, `color?red` or something.

I'm no programmer, so I'm not familiar with the syntax of programming languages (except shell script and things like `gawk`/`sed` etc.) so I can't compare their syntax with that of TeX/TikZ/Forest.

But this is about text markup and *any* character therefore has the potential to be used in content. In many programming languages, at least, all such content would need some kind of protection (e.g. by being quoted). That would be a pain when typing a document (or a tree), but the price of not doing that may be knowing when protection *is* needed. Of course, we could make some new characters to avoid this, but then nobody will be able to type it.

You could, however, argue that Forest should parse everything until the first comma as content and protect it suitably when passed to TikZ. You would still need to protect `=` etc. in other cases e.g. specifying `label` or whatever. So possibly it would be even more confusing.

Essentially, I think the point is that markup of natural language is in many ways more complex than the design of syntax for a regular programming language needs to be.

Note that we can avoid ambiguity by surrounding the content of *all* nodes, `label`s etc. with curly brackets. Then we don't have to think about whether this one in particular needs protection. If we remember that what we're giving is essentially a key-value list, though, I think it becomes much clearer where protection is specifically required.